# GIT deleting remote orgin repository, and changing default one

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, vps

need help of git-guru)))

Status quo is this:

- I created my project locally, pushed everything to github.
- I git clone project to VPS from github
- As time have passed, there emerged the need to migrate from github to bitbucket(financial issues)
- Now when I pull my changes from bitbucket I have to `git pull bitbucket [branch_name]`

**QUESTION:**

Currently I want to delete my origin repository from github, I got 2 questions:

- Whether It will break anything in my VPS. I mean github was my
  original repo, so won't it be any buttburning issues?
- How can I make my bitbucket repo as a default one, so that I don't
  have to type:

  git pull bitbucket [branch_name]

  but instead, just type:

  git pull [branch_name]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change `origin` to point to your bitbucket url, and then remove your bitbucket remote. You have to do this both on your VPS and locally. It should not break anything in your VPS.

If you do a `git remote -v` you'll see origin pointing to github

```
origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
bitbucket  git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git(fetch)
bitbucket  git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

To change it, simply use:

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Verify the changes by running `git remote -v` again

```
origin  git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git(fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
bitbucket  git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git(fetch)
bitbucket  git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

To remove your bitbucket remote

```
git remote rm bitbucket
```

Then run `git remote -v` again and you should only see `origin`

```
origin  git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git(fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Comment: Thank you, git-guru :)))